# Angular/jest window._satellite.track cannot get track of type undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to test an external function that gets stored in the window object and is called via window._satellite.track('exampleevent') in jest, the problem is this function isn't added to the window object until a script is added in html by a 3rd party vendor, so ng test doesnt have access to it and says satellite is undefined which is true.

How do I test this in jest/angular9? 
Edit: my lines covered goes down so I have to maintain a code coverage percentage and its dropping it.

Code:

```
this.taggingService.createtag(string1,string2)

 Inside tagging service we have
createtag(string1,string2){
window._satellite.track('exampleevent')
}
```

Comment: What is the point of spending time on writing unit test against an external function that was written by other developers? As this external function is supposed to be maintained by its author?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the code that your unit test will try to test against.

Comment: I have to test this because its showing up as a line that's not covered in my testing.I just added some code.